# what encryption is this? 44 chars, ending with =

Tags: encryption

Basically I tried a lot of different decryption but I can't find it.

I am pretty sure it is an encryption method and not a hash, since the data has to be used.

They are all 44 characters long and end with `=`

Examples:

```
5yFKMmoA+QNC1ch4islRw2l11jHkUD7xrhN2g4v+lok=
6n08mzA1AwzSQHkw9pLVg/AqjDlgz7gUFCDbnSX6irI=
Y7ewexuPNgRAf2sz3qQ26by2p1M2fQ8z6NaM5mniWkg=
```

Comment: Where did you get these examples? How is the data used? (It looks like Base64, but what's encoded in those in some binary format itself.)

Comment: This is most likely just [Base64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) encoded binary data. It's possible that the binary data is, itself, the output of some encryption algorithm, but it's impossible to give any more details on that.

Comment: It from a newsletter script I made awhile, but I lost the files and only got the database so now I want to recode but I am stuck on the decryption

Comment: They are base64 encoded 32-byte sequences. They look pretty random to the naked eye. They can be anything, but my first guess would be sha256 hashes.

Answer (score 3):

Seems that are Base64-encoded 33-byte strings (44*6=264/8=33).

See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64

Comment: It seems like it's base64 however when I decode them I am getting alot of odd character so I am not sure if they are double encoded

Comment: They are 32 byte sequences, not 33 bytes.